# Unity - One client can control all player objects using gamepad (Netcode and Input System)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, multiplayer

**TL;DR Clients can control only their player objects with keyboard, but all players with gamepad (using Netcode for Game Objects, Unity Input System and a PS4 Controller)**

I am working on a multiplayer game and I am relatively new to multiplayer programming. I am using Netcode for GameObjects.

I am using Unity Input System for handling inputs and I created 2 action maps currently. One for movements (with keyboard and gamepad) and one for attacking (with keyboard, gamepad and mouse).

I am trying to move the players in a Server Authoritative way; thus, I am using Server RPCs for handling movements.

The issue I am having is that, when I play with a Gamepad (PS4 controller), one of the clients can control the others. However, it works perfectly with Keyboard actions.

The code I'm using for the player movement is below:

```
[RequireComponent(typeof(Rigidbody))]
public class PlayerMovement : NetworkBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private Rigidbody _rb;
    [SerializeField] private float movementSpeed = 10f;
    [SerializeField] private float jumpSpeed = 8f;

    Vector3 _movementVector;

    private PlayerInputActions playerInputActions;

    private PlayerInputActions PlayerInputActions
    {
        get
        {
            if(playerInputActions != null)
            {
                return playerInputActions;
            }
            return playerInputActions = new PlayerInputActions();
        }
    }

    public override void OnNetworkSpawn()
    {
        if(!IsOwner) { return; }
        PlayerInputActions.PlayerMovement.Movement.performed += ctx => SetMovement(ctx.ReadValue<Vector2>());
        PlayerInputActions.PlayerMovement.Movement.canceled += ctx => SetMovement(Vector2.zero);
        PlayerInputActions.PlayerMovement.Jump.performed += PerformJump;
    }

    public override void OnNetworkDespawn()
    {
        if (!IsOwner) { return; }
        PlayerInputActions.PlayerMovement.Movement.performed -= ctx => SetMovement(ctx.ReadValue<Vector2>());
        PlayerInputActions.PlayerMovement.Movement.canceled -= ctx => SetMovement(Vector2.zero);
        PlayerInputActions.PlayerMovement.Jump.performed -= PerformJump;
    }

    private void OnEnable() => PlayerInputActions.Enable();

    private void OnDisable() => PlayerInputActions.Disable();

    private void SetMovement(Vector2 inputVector) => _movementVector = new Vector3(inputVector.x, 0.0f, 0.0f);

    private void PerformJump(InputAction.CallbackContext obj)
    {
        if (!IsOwner) { return; }
        Vector3 jumpVector = Vector3.up;
        HandleJumpServerRpc(jumpVector);
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        if(!IsLocalPlayer) { return; }
        HandleMovement();
    }

    private void HandleMovement()
    {
        if (!IsOwner) { return; }
        HandleMovementServerRpc(_movementVector);
    }

    #region Server

    [ServerRpc]
    private void HandleMovementServerRpc(Vector3 movementVector)
    {
        if(Vector3.Distance(movementVector, Vector3.zero) > 0.000001f)
        {
            Debug.Log($"Owner ID: {OwnerClientId}");
            _rb.MovePosition(transform.position + movementVector * Time.deltaTime * movementSpeed);
        }
    }

    [ServerRpc]
    private void HandleJumpServerRpc(Vector3 jumpVector)
    {
        if (_rb.velocity.y == 0f)
        {
            _rb.AddForce(jumpVector * jumpSpeed, ForceMode.Impulse);
        }
            
    }

    private void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)
    {
        Debug.Log($"Collided with: {collision.gameObject.name}");
    }

    #endregion
}
```

And following is the Action Map I created for movement:
[image: Action Map]

I thought the issue is with the Unity Input System event subscriptions, but I could not find a fix so far for it.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this will work but I did

```
public override void OnNetworkSpawn(){
    if (!IsOwner) Destroy(this); 
}
```